# Failure to create private gallery atom feed with VsixUtil.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I am following the instruction in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-create-vsix-feed-for-private-gallery?view=vs-2022 by running the tool where I have the compiled VSIX file:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin\VsixUtil.exe' createVsixFeed
```

But it fails with

```
VSSDK: error VsixFeed0001 :  'C:\Users\Assaf Sapir\Downloads\test\extension.vsix' - This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest's format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted.
VSSDK: error VsixFeed0002 : Could not create a VSIX feed file because of error '1'
```

I don't think the VSIX is corrupted because I can install it. trying to run with `-ignoreErrors` yields the same results.

Do I have to use this tool? Is it possible to create the ATOM XML manually? how?

Answer (score 0):

There is another utility that works better than Microsoft's own VsixFeed util for this subject.
Unfortunately the spec for private galeries' ATOM feed isn't published by Microsoft and isn't clear (only an "[example entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-create-vsix-feed-for-private-gallery?view=vs-2022#example-of-vsix-entry)"), so we're left with second-guessing the Vsix specs (which are indeed [documented for package manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix-extension-schema-2-0-reference?view=vs-2022)), leaving some gaps for things like how to process metadata fields (e.g. "More info" links from Vsix to the gallery's xml).

You might have more luck with the PrivateGalleryCreator util linked at [MS Devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/create-a-private-gallery-for-self-hosted-visual-studio-extensions/) (associated with the open-source repo https://github.com/madskristensen/PrivateGalleryCreator ). This will help you create the basics of your gallery's xml. For editing I've personally just turned to homemade Powershell scripts, since Microsoft's utilities on this matter are very much lacking.